# Hyper-V: determine the guest's name given the GUID

Tags: scripting, hyper-v

How would I go about determining the guest's name given its GUID or vice-versa, preferably with only the Hyper-V/Server Core stock install at hands?

Rationale:

I am in favor of having a repository of dirty tricks to revert to when in great need. To immediately quiesce all (storage) operations of a VM guest without losing the state, I used to run `kill 17 <all VM's virtual processes>` (signaling *SIGSTOP*) and resumed afterwards using `kill 19 <all VM's virtual processes>` (signaling *SIGCONT*) in ESXi/vSphere shell.

I tried the same technique with Hyper-V using Process Explorer's "Suspend" functionality on the `vmwp.exe` processes and it seemed to work. I have yet to find a way for easily identifying the processes to suspend, though - the vmwp command line is only listing a GUID.

Comment: Which version of Hyper-V?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf 3 (2012), although prior versions would be of interest as well (you never know what's around the corner).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PowerShell type:

```
get-vm | ft VMName, VMId
```

This gives you a list of all existing VMs with their name and ID.

You can then use all the other PowerShell goodness to do something with that information.